# Append to csv or create a new sheet in same csv

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, lambda

The Script belows involves two parts. Fetching the security groups of account A and account B.
When It writes to csv, it first writes the security groups of account A and then overwrites the same csv with security groups 
of account B. So when I download the file, it contains only the results from account B.

I need a solution either to append the security groups of B to the same sheet, Or to create a new sheet for account B in the same CSV. Please guide me how to achieve it.

Thanks for reading.

```
import boto3
import csv
import io
from io import BytesIO
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

a_dev_client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context): 

    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    b_dev = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::2222222222222:role/Unused_Security_Groups',
        RoleSessionName='test'
    )

    b_dev_client = boto3.resource(
        'ec2',
        region_name='eu-west-1',
        aws_access_key_id=b_dev["Credentials"]["AccessKeyId"],
        aws_secret_access_key=b_dev["Credentials"]["SecretAccessKey"],
        aws_session_token=b_dev["Credentials"]["SessionToken"]
    )

    def a_dev():
        Account_Name = 'A'
        regions = ['eu-west-1','eu-west-2','us-east-2','us-west-1','us-west-2','us-east-1','ap-northeast-2','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1','ca-central-1','eu-west-3']
        csvio = io.BytesIO()
        writer = csv.writer(csvio)
        writer.writerow([
            'Account Name',
            'Region',
            'SecurityGroup-Id'
        ])
        for region in regions:
            ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)
            sgs = list(ec2.security_groups.all())
            insts = list(ec2.instances.all())
            all_sgs = set([sg.group_id for sg in sgs])
            all_inst_sgs = set([sg['GroupId'] for inst in insts for sg in
            inst.security_groups])
            unused_sgs = all_sgs - all_inst_sgs
            for elem in unused_sgs:
                writer.writerow([
                    Account_Name,
                    region,
                    elem
                    ])
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.put_object(Body=csvio.getvalue(), ContentType='application/vnd.ms-excel', Bucket='######', Key='Unused_Security_Groups.csv', ACL='public-read') 

        csvio.close()
        s3.get_object(Bucket='#######', Key='Unused_Security_Groups.csv') 

    a_dev()

    def b_dev():
        Account_Name = 'B'
        #regions = ['eu-west-1','eu-west-2','us-east-2','us-west-1','us-west-2','us-east-1','ap-northeast-2','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1','ca-central-1','eu-west-3']
        regions = ['eu-west-1']

        csvio = io.BytesIO()
        writer = csv.writer(csvio)
        writer.writerow([
            'Account Name',
            'Region',
            'SecurityGroup-Id'
        ])
        for region in regions:
            #ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)
            sgs = list(b_dev_client.security_groups.all())
            insts = list(b_dev_client.instances.all())
            all_sgs = set([sg.group_id for sg in sgs])
            all_inst_sgs = set([sg['GroupId'] for inst in insts for sg in
            inst.security_groups])
            unused_sgs = all_sgs - all_inst_sgs
            for elem in unused_sgs:
                writer.writerow([
                    Account_Name,
                    region,
                    elem
                    ])
        s3 = boto3.client('s3')
        s3.put_object(Body=csvio.getvalue(), ContentType='application/vnd.ms-excel', Bucket='#######', Key='Unused_Security_Groups.csv', ACL='public-read') 

        csvio.close()
        s3.get_object(Bucket='#######', Key='Unused_Security_Groups.csv') 

    b_dev()
```

Update:

After I try to append the csv, I am getting "Read-only File System" Error.

```
    def b_dev():
        Account_Name = '2'
        regions = ['us-west-1']

        csvio = io.BytesIO()
        writer = csv.writer(csvio)
        fields=['Account Name','Region','SecurityGroup-Id']
        with open('Unused_Security_Groups.csv', 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(fields)
            for region in regions:
                #ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=region)
                sgs = list(bi_dev_client.security_groups.all())
                insts = list(bi_dev_client.instances.all())
                all_sgs = set([sg.group_id for sg in sgs])
                all_inst_sgs = set([sg['GroupId'] for inst in insts for sg in
                inst.security_groups])
                unused_sgs = all_sgs - all_inst_sgs
                for elem in unused_sgs:
                    writer.writerow([
                        Account_Name,
                        region,
                        elem
                        ])
            s3 = boto3.client('s3')
            s3.put_object(Body=csvio.getvalue(), ContentType='application/vnd.ms-excel', Bucket='######', Key='Unused_Security_Groups.csv', ACL='public-read') 

            csvio.close()
            s3.get_object(Bucket='######', Key='Unused_Security_Groups.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

First *add a new sheet to a csv file* is plain non sense. **A CSV file is not an Excel file**. It is a sequential text file this is automatically processed by Excel as a spreadsheet. But it has no support for multiple sheets.

But it is easy to *append* to a csv file: just open the file in append mode (`"a"`) instead of overwrite mode (`"w"`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. When I trying to append I am getting an error "Read Only file system. Can you please guide on this..

Comment: @itechworkerz: Of course you must have write permission on the file... That is not a programming problem, and I cannot help you with that.

Comment: The File in the s3 has the write permission, because the first function(Account A) writes to the file.
I assume the problem in the code, as its not writing(append) to the CSV. The problem I feel is with the code that I updated. Please check and guide.
Thank You

Comment: `    with open('Unused_Security_Groups.csv', 'a') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(fields)
`
The problem is here.